# Spring cloud config not apply global configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm having a problem on spring cloud configuration 2020.0.3, spring boot 2.4.5 for details:

- Yaml configuration file is following [Multi-profile YAML documents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml)
- I have a configuration yaml file on the config server.

my_cofig.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/default_db"
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    username: my_db
    password: 12345
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dev_db"
```

- I have loaded the config from the config server by browser, it's correct.
  But:
- When I run Spring application with specific configuration (e.g. dev), Spring application must not apply global configuration variables defined on configuration file from configuration server. It only loads dev's configuration variables.

bootstrap.yaml

```
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  application:
    name: auth-service
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      fail-fast: true
      allow-override: true
      profile: dev
      uri: http://localhost:5000
```

Error detail:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Please help me, many thanks!

Comment: not visible here, but have you added the spaces in `profiles`? yaml is pretty dramatic about spaces and tabs

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yaml is in the correct format!

Comment: What does /actuator/env say? What version of spring boot?

Comment: I am using spring boot version: 2.4.5.
Console log:
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I solved the problem by upgrading spring boot version to 2.5.1
Thanks all

Comment: If that is the case, don't forget to accept your answer as the correct one so that the question is rendered as "answered" ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  profiles:
```

This does not exist (it was deprecated if I am not mistaken). Please check the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.profiles.active).

I believe that what you are looking for is the following ([reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.config.activate.on-profile)):

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/default_db"
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    username: my_db
    password: 12345
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dev_db"
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, i am following [Multi-profile YAML documents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml) to compose yaml configuration file.
I have tried your solution, but it still not work.